# Weird compression question

Tags: centos, compression, file-comparison

I'm trying to compress some raw sensor data from older recordings that I need and don't want to remove from my Centos server.

The data recorded is in a proprietary format, but for all intents and purposes we can characterize it as 306 channel PCM 32-bit audio recordings at 1000 Hz. With a few hundred lines of clear text meta data in the header of the file. Files range from 100mb to 1.9GB in directories around 7GB, processed file directories can be up to 60GB containing copies of raw data with filters applied to data.

Here is the weird bit. I can compress the raw data down to 30% of original size with bzip2 and 26% of original with pxz.
Similar results with lzrip using ZPAQ. But processed data PCM 32bit variable I can only shave 10 to 12 percent off. 16 bit short processed data, I can compress it to about 50% of original size. Processing data simplifies the recording data and there is less variation in the recording.

Any suggestions? Any one have something similar? I want as much space saving as possible on the processed data, and plan to check the data after to make sure it has no errors. Any idea why simplified data out from processing is less compressible than raw?

//edit - looking at FLAC but converting back to original format may be problematic. Not impossible .. Still looking.

//solution edit. FLAC did not like 370 channels of data. But I was able to gain some compression by creating my own large dictionary and training it with segments of the large files.

Comment: Have you try FLAC, APE? They use zip, but they are audio oriented

Comment: Without some information what kind of sensor data it is, it's difficult to say -- compression relies a lot on guessing structure in the data, and encoding the structures with higher probability (lower entropy) by shorter sequences. So likely the 16 bit are less random than the 32 bit. If it's really like audio, have you tried lossless audio compression, e.g. FLAC?

Comment: @RomeoNinov technically it is only like audio very similar to it. But has extensive meta info relating to the subjects and settings. Also contains 3d model information as points in 3d space as part of the header. Not sure if FLAC or APE will keep that info. It also has to be lossless for it to be useful after compression.

Comment: @dirkt I'm looking into seeing if I can shove it into FLAC. The recordings are 1000 Hz magneto electro encephalogram data that records magnetic fields caused by electrical potential shifts in the brain. The recording data is similar to PCM 32 bit audio. But the confusing thing is doing source filtering reduces randomness of the data but kills the compressability vs raw. Unfortunately the documentation isn't very detailed on the specifications of the raw data. So all I know is raw is 32bit but may not be variable bit.

Comment: @RomeoNinov other problem is converting it back. The software we use would need the original format to read it.

Comment: Do you have documentation about the format? Write a small program to convert original format into a PCM wav + metadata +3d data, and back. If it's a superposition of signals on different frequencies, it should compress well with lossless audio compression algorithms. There are various ways to store the metadata in the compressed audio, depending on the container format.

Comment: @dirkt Good idea, there are some 3rd party utilities that I can extract meta data and 3d points. I was really hopping for a magic setting in Pxz or something. Do you know if FLAC acts like a data wrapper or does it reprocess the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have documentation about the format? Write a small program to convert original format into a PCM wav + metadata +3d data, and back. If it's a superposition of signals on different frequencies, it should compress well with lossless audio compression algorithms, like FLAC.

FLAC is like MP3: It compresses audio data by rewriting it into a different format. So it's not what I would call a "wrapper" (I wouldn't call any compression program a "wrapper"). But unlike MP3, the compressions is lossless: When you decompress, you get exactly the same data, just like in bzip2 etc. Compression ratio for FLAC on audio data is about 50%.

There are various ways to store the metadata in the compressed audio, depending on the container format. It's also possible to just put all three files in an archive file, format of your chouce, though the compressed PCM data won't be compressed further.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm going to start working on this to see if there are any differences in the end data.

Comment: Do you know of any compressors that use learning like ZSTD to create a dictionary? ZSTD even on max performs poorly until using its learning on the data i am using. After learning it is able to compress to 60% original size

Comment: No, I don't know any ZSTD compressors, sorry.